# How to listen cascade remove with Event suscriber / Listner with Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I would need to listen to the cascade remove event.
Let me explain :

I have an Entity Brand an Entity Video. 
For a video, I have One Brand, gallery with gallery items and each galleryItem have a media

Entity Video :

```
 /**
     * @var Brand
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand", fetch="EAGER")
     * @JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $brand;

/**
     * @var Gallery
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Gallery", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attachments_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $attachments;
```

Entity Gallery :

```
/**
     * Unidirectional OneToMany relationship.
     *
     * @var GalleryItem[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="GalleryItem", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER", orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="gallery_galleryitems",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(unique=true, onDelete="CASCADE")}
     * )
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
     */
    private $galleryItems;
```

Entity GalleryItem

```
/**
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     * @var Media
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Media", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $media;
```

I would like when I delete a brand, the medias are also deleted.

My first problem is : When I delete the brand, the videos are deleted but not the attachments.

In addition I would like to perform operations (delete files on the server, ...) when I delete a brand.

So I tried to create an event subscriber but I do not fit in the condition.

```
public function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {

        $media = $args->getEntity();

        if ($media instanceof Media) {
            dump("test");
            exit;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Even if you make this work (which might not be possible, since the `CASCADE` will be triggered and handled by the DB), I believe this is the wrong idea. You are letting your DB drive your application, when it should be the other way around.

Comment: First glance in UnitOfWork tells me, that cascaded entities should invoke lifecycle events. But @yivi tells it, you should remove the cascade option and listen to gallery events, then remove the videos there by yourself.

Comment: @Rawburner `ON DELETE CASCADE` would be dealt by the DB directly. I do not believe Doctrine would be aware of this happening at all (beyond the schema definition), right?

Comment: @yivi look at \Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork::doRemove, there is a function called cascadeRemove which go through cascaded entities and end again in doRemove, which invokes Livecycle events.